# What is your approach to write unit tests for linked classes?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I was thinking about unit tests in my all projects. And I faced interesting question. I always create isolated test class for each class. Test class tests only one class, all external functionallity is mocked. Should I create test class for each class that I want to check? 
I mean if I have a few classes in the same package, e.g.:

```
-org.mySample.dictionaries
--DictionaryConverter.java
--DictionaryDaService.java
```

And DictionaryDaService uses DictionaryConverter for any purposes. It means that I can test **DictionaryConverter** class through the **DictionaryDaService**.

I'm pretty sure it's not really good practise because it will be a lot of connections between **DictionaryDaServiceTests** and **DictionaryConverter** original class. Another words, I break concept about associations between classes. My test passing depends on two classes the same time.

But the point is that in the company project I often faces same unit tests. 
Just wanted to get some points of view and more expierence about other developers approaches in that case.

What would you do? Do you create each test class for each class? Or there is no precisely right concept how to write tests?

Comment: This boils down to the questioon *what is a `unit`?* I like the answer of *Roy Osherove* in [The Art of Unit Testing](https://www.amazon.com/Art-Unit-Testing-Roy-Osherove/dp/1617290890): *A unit is all the code that has the same reason to change.*

Comment: I sometimes use component tests that test a few classes together.  https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ComponentTest.html

Answer (score 3):

Test stuff that makes sense.

If each of `DictionaryConverter` and `DictionaryDaService` are independent, and each one can be used separately and in a different context then it is better to unit test each one separately.

If, on the other hand, `DictionaryDaService` will be used only by `DictionaryService` or vice versa, then testing the owner object should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to [When to use stubs/mocks and when to use real objects in unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48176358/when-to-use-stubs-mocks-and-when-to-use-real-objects-in-unit-testing/48177539?noredirect=1#comment83336087_48177539)

My answer there was the first concern is to write a good unit test, a test who reflect an intention (meaningful one) as Yamenk said. Doesn't matter if you are testing one method/ one class... as long as your test is fast, isolated, repeatable, self validating and Thorough and Timely (F.I.R.S.T).

It happens that if you are decoupling right your code then you could catch your intention in one unit being in one class...